# Remove Seasonality before applying SARIMA model on weekly data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prediction, arima

I am trying to predict average weekly stock prices for time series data.

Steps I followed:

1. I tested the data to check whether it was stationary or not using `ADF` and `KPSS` tests.
2. Next, to make the data stationary - I normalized the data using `StandardScaler`, Removed the trend by taking the first difference, removed the increasing volatility, removed seasonality
3. I then plotted `ACF` and `PACF` graphs to identify the `MA` and `AR` lags.
4. I modelled the values for `ARIMA` model and it seems to give an awful performance

I was thinking to apply `SARIMA` model next, but I am not sure if I should have removed seasonality before since `SARIMA` takes seasonality into account.

I would really appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

As for SARIMA, it's definitely a good idea to take seasonality into account, but it may depend on the specifics of your data. Have you tried looking at the seasonal decomposition of your time series? That could help you determine whether you need to include seasonality in your model.

Also, keep in mind that sometimes even the best models can give poor performance. It might be worth exploring other methods of prediction, such as machine learning algorithms or hybrid models.

Comment: Following is the snapshot of the original data -

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Uqg.png

Since, this data look multiplicative ; Following is the snapshot of the decomposition of the time series
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOkBT.png

Comment: Since SARIMA already takes into account of seasonality and integration; can I pass the raw data to my model which is non stationary or I should make it stationary and then pass the transformed stationary data to the fit the model? @pigsalaciarat